# Sorting pandas dataframe vectorized way

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

The sample input dataframe is as follows

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,1,4,7,6], [5,6,3,7,np.nan], [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]], columns=["A", "B","C","D","E"])
```

Expected Output

```
df_output=pd.DataFrame([[-1,-1,0,1,1],[-1,-1,0,1,1],[-1,1,-1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0]],columns=["A", "B","C","D","E"])
```

Here is what I am trying.
1) Sort every row.

2)Assign -1 to half of smallest valid observations and +1 to largest valid observations.

3) NaN needs to have zero.

4) In case of odd number of columns, the median needs to have zero.

The following code works well for even number of columns.

```
df_input[:] = np.where(df_input.rank(axis=1) > df_input.shape[1] / 2, 1, -1)
```

How do I expand this to odd number of columns and account for NaN.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add sample data with 3 columns with expected output? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also with `NaN`s

Comment: Edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
a = df_input.rank(axis=1)
x = df_input.shape[1] / 2

m1 = a < x
m2 = a > x
m3 = (a.eq(a.mean(axis=1), axis=0))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.select([m3, m2, m1], [0, 1, -1], 0), columns=df_input.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0 -1 -1  0  1  1
1 -1 -1  0  1  1
2 -1  1 -1  1  0
3  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni - Some problem?

Comment: m1 = a.eq(a.max(axis=1), axis=0) is making only one column as true. How can I expand this to more than 3 columns

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni - Can you create sample DataFrame with e.g. 5 columns? Because it seems I dont understand what you need. :(

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are using a string for the NAN ('NAN').

then:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,1,4,7,6], [5,6,3,7,np.nan], [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]], columns=["A", "B","C","D","E"])

    df_input
        A   B   C   D   E
0   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
1   2.0 1.0 4.0 7.0 6.0
2   5.0 6.0 3.0 7.0 NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

df2 = df_input.copy()
df2[:] = np.where(df2.isna(), 0, np.where(df2.rank(axis=1) > df2.shape[1] / 2, 1, -1))

df2

        A   B   C   D   E
0   -1  -1  1   1   1
1   -1  -1  1   1   1
2   -1  1   -1  1   0
3   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Can you explain what am I missing in my answer?